# Error when creating an Xbox 360 game template for indie games?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna, xbox360

I'm trying to look at how hard it'd be to write an indie game for Xbox. However, I can't even create the template after installing XNA Game Studio.

I just get

> An error was encountered creating the subproject "ProjectName"
>
> Object reference not set to instance of an object

and then the project that gets created is just a blank project. What could be wrong with this? I tried a reinstall of game studio and am creating this from Visual Studio 2010, though I have 2012 installed also

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had two sets of XNA installed. I had "XNA 4.0" and "XNA 4.0 Refresh". Not sure why they didn't detect each other as installed. To fix it though, I uninstalled both(including redistributables) and did a fresh install with the latest version available from Microsoft. Everything worked fine afterwards

Comment: @AllonGuralnek I know. "you can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: That restriction actually applies to hi-rep users? That's plain silly.